# How to pass the jquery's ajax response data to outer function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Am getting data from ajax call and appending the data to table. Am getting title and url from the data. Now when i click on the url data of table , i need to call a outer javascript function with the clicked url data.

```
 <script>

 jquery(document).ready(function(){
   jquery(#button).click(function{
  showData();  
 });
 });


function showData(){
var total  = "";
var final = ""; 
  jquery.ajax({
url : "AJAX_POST_URL",
type: "POST",
data : input,
    dataType: "json",
success: function(jsondata)
{
    //data - response from server
     var document= jsondata.data.results;  //am getting array of objects
     for(int i=0; i<document.length; i++){
      var tr = "<tr>";
    var td = "<td>" + "Title : " +
    document[i].title + "Url :" + "<a href=''>" +  document[i].url + </a> + "</td></tr>";
   final = tr + td;
    total= total + final ;
        }

    $("#docTable").append(total) ;

},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
{
            alert("error");
}
});
}
</script>


<script>
function download(){

  //inside this function i need to get the value of document[i].url
}
</script>
```

Comment: @adeneo : I have read the link..but I need to catch the data after clicking on data of the table and pass it to outer function.? how to do that?

Comment: could anybody help me in getting this...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should structure your program quite a bit better, and it would be easier if you could put your complete example up on jsfiddle.net.

But a quick solution in your current code may be to make "document" a global variable. Beware that document already is a global variable in the BOM (Browser Object Model), so use something else like say "docs".

```
<script>
// Global variable
var docs;

jquery(document).ready(function(){
  jquery(#button).click(function{
    showData();  
  });
});

function showData(){
  var total  = "";
  var final = "";

  jquery.ajax({
    url : "AJAX_POST_URL",
    type: "POST",
    data : input,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(jsondata)
    {
      //data - response from server
      docs = jsondata.data.results;  //am getting array of objects

      for(int i=0; i<document.length; i++) {
        var tr = "<tr>";
        var td = "<td>" + "Title : " +
        docs[i].title + "Url :" + "<a href=''>" +  docs[i].url + </a> + "</td></tr>";
        final = tr + td;
        total = total + final;
      }

      $("#docTable").append(total) ;
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      alert("error");
    }
  });
}
</script>


<script>
function download(){    
  //inside this function i need to get the value of document[i].url

  // You have access to docs through the global variable
  for(var i=0;i < docs.length;i++) {
    console.log(docs[i].url)
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Hallvar..! Can i know one more thing. Actually When i click on the data of the table, i was calling the function 'download'. so how i can i come to know that specific url . here as per the answer , am getting whole docs, but i need to get the specific url data when i click on the table url data.

Comment: @Hallvar...Yeah i agree. from next time, i will post it in jsfiddle.net

Comment: If you just want to send the browser to the url of the doc, then you do not need the download function. You can instead change "<a href=''>" to '<a href="'+docs[i].url+'">'. When the user clicks the url the browser will open that url.

Comment: No..What i mean to say is that, When i click on the url's of table data, i need to invoke a java method , so when i click on the url , i was writing a js function which inturn calls java method, but how to pass the clicked url to the js function , so that from there i can pass to java method

Comment: I assume by java method you mean a WebService/REST URL of some sort. Either set the URL to the WebService/REST in the href. Or '<a onclick="function() { download(\''+docs[i].url+'\'); }">'. Then the download function looks something like "function download(url) { console.log(url); }". This is not very pretty code, but it is difficult to show a better way without a more complete example.

Comment: @Hallvar... check the html and javascript editor field from this link..http://jsfiddle.net/NN5hj/1/

Comment: Then shall i need to write like this ---> '<a onclick="function() { download(\''+docs[i].url+'\'); }">' and outer function as --> "function download(url){ console.log(url);}". Am  i right?

Comment: can i know why are those "\" in before and after url value?

Comment: That is to pass the url as a string into the download function. We are writing javascript code from within javascript (usually a bad idea) Since docs[i].url will return the value of the string without the quotes, we need to put the quotes back when constructing the javascript. A much better idea is to attach and onclick event handler from JavaScript. Or even better use a framework such as Knockout.js to make your code much cleaner and clearer.

Comment: am at beginner level of javascript and jquery..so i was asking 'n' number of questions?

Comment: Once again Thanks for answering all my questions..! Now am clear

Comment: @Hallvar.. I tried with your code '<a onclick="function() { download(\''+docs[i].url+'\'); }">'. But when i click on the url, the js function is not at all getting called.

Comment: Sorry it should be: '<a onclick="download(\''+docs[i].url+'\');">'.