# html anchor tag's onclick was not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I was generating a table dynamically. 
    Inside the td data , there is a hyperlink.inturn it should call a function. 
    why the below code snippet was not working. Nothing happening when i click on the link.

```
  <a href='#' onclick='function(){alert('hiii');}'>
```

Comment: my code snippet is like : var td ="< a href='#' onclick='function(){alert('hiii');}' >";

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of conflicting `'` and a funciton definition instead of call (thanks @user1389596):

```
<a href='#' onclick="alert('hiii')">
```

that should work. The extra `'`s inside of the onclick made the browser view it as the end of the onclick attribute, which isn't what you want. This way, using two different types of quotes, it works fine.

Or, even better, don't use inline handlers:

```
<a href='#' id="thethingy">
<!--in a galaxy far, far away:-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
        document.getElementById('thethingy').addEventListener('click',function(){
            alert('hiii');
        },false);
    },false);
</script>
```

Comment: @Markasoftware -
still not able to call the function...! var td= "<td>"+ doc[i] + '</br>' +doc[j]  + '<br/>' + '<a href="#" onclick="function(){alert('hiih');}">' + "</td>" .  Am getting error : Expected ;

Comment: @Markasoftware - Please refer this link for complete code..! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722421/how-to-pass-the-jquerys-ajax-response-data-to-outer-function

Answer (score 4):

Event handlers added via `innerHTML` will not trigger in some cases for security reasons.  It's also incorrect to include `function ()` since all this `onclick` would do is *define* an anonymous function and do nothing else.  You also have conflicting quotes.

If you are using jQuery, event delegation would make this simpler.  Exclude `onclick` entirely and use something like:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function () { alert("hiii"); });
```

`document` and `a` selectors should be as specific as possible.

You can also bind events to elements added to the DOM as needed.

Answer (score 3):

## 1st Issue

```
onclick='function(){alert('hiii');}'
```

This seriously is wrongly coded as per the ***use of quotes***. The proper usage should be any of the following

### Proper use of quotes

```
onclick='function(){alert("hiii");}'
```

or

```
onclick="function(){alert('hiii');}"
```

***This much only about the syntax. But there is still something to be done to actually call the function at runtime. Without proper invocation the function will not be executed. That is the 2nd issue.***

## 2nd Issue

Now there are 2 syntax that you may follow to actually execute the function at runtime.

### 1st syntax:

```
(function(){...})();
```

So the code should be-

```
onclick="(function(){alert('hiii');})();"
```

**[Fiddle Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/RLGLy/1/)**

### 2nd syntax

```
new function(){...};
```

So the code should be-

```
onclick="new function(){alert('hiii');};"
```

**[Fiddle demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/RLGLy/)**

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a function... not calling it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <a href="javascript:alert('hi');">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `onclick="function(){alert('hiii');}"`. You may try this code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('hiii');">
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have updated quotes now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a onclick='function(){alert('hiii');}' href='#' >
```

try this one it will work without any problem, no need for event listeners

Comment: Don't forget to add 4 spaces indentation for code lines. Even better: just select all the code then do CMD + K. (I've already done it)

Answer (score 0):

Although this a quotes problem. Following will solve your problem.

```
<a href='#' onclick="alert('hiii')">
```

In case you are using Vue.js like me onclick will not work. You can use this.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" @click="alert('hiii')">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be of help to someone,
At first I thought it was due to the fact that href was present, and inserted before the onclick event.

However here is a sample of an a tag that calls a function and passing a parameter.

Both Samples has the onclick event and href properties in different orders.

```js
function helloWorld(message){
  alert('Hello world! : ' + message);
};
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick="helloWorld('href before onclick')">Click Me (href then onclick)</a>
<br>
<br>
<a onclick="helloWorld('onclick before href')" href="#">Click Me (onclick then href)</a>
```

};